# Integrating a html in var in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a simple html suppose

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span>Customer Type  </span>
</td>
<td>
<input id="TxtCustomerName" name="TxtCustomerName" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

now i am trying to generate an html in window popup as

```
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100')

var html="<body><table><tbody><tr>";
html+="<td><span>Customer Type</span></td>";
html+="<td><input id="TxtCustomerName" name="TxtCustomerName" type="text"></td>"
html+="</tr></tbody></table><body>";

alert(html);
myWindow.document.write(html)
myWindow.focus()
```

But the opoup doesnt appear. Moreover due to the control input text this error is occuring.
Help me in integrating a control in html variable so the popup appear with control.

Comment: Just a question - but why a new window, and not a modal (assuming you CAN use jQuery and jQuery UI) http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Comment: Also, `document.write` is frowned upon. You can still use `innerHtml` though: get rid of `<body>` and `</body>` and use `myWindow.document.body.innerHtml = html;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotation marks are messed up. Try:

```
html+="<td><input id='TxtCustomerName' name='TxtCustomerName' type='text'></td>";
```

Quotes in strings should be preceded by a backslash. This allows the JavaScript interpreter to distinguish a quote within the string from the quotes that serve as string delimiters. Here's an example:

```
string1='It\'s five o\'clock!';
string2="<A HREF=\"index.htm\">";
```

Alternatively, if your string includes single quotes only, then you can use double quotes as string delimiters, and vice versa. Here's an example:

```
string1="It's five o'clock!";
string2='<A HREF="index.htm">';
```

Reference: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/quotesin.htm

Answer (score 0):

Look how JS syntax is highlighted. `"TxtCustomerName"` is not what you expect, because `"`" is ending the string. Should be

```
html+="<td><input id='TxtCustomerName' name='TxtCustomerName' type='text'></td>";
```

Or you can escape these `"`

```
html+="<td><input id=\"TxtCustomerName\" name=\"TxtCustomerName\" type=\"text\"></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  html+="<td><input id='TxtCustomerName' name='TxtCustomerName' type='text'></td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotation marks and you forgot the end colon:

```html
html += "<td><input id=\"TxtCustomerName\" name=\"TxtCustomerName\" type=\"text\"></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing to escape double quotes `"`

```
html+="<td><input id='TxtCustomerName' name='TxtCustomerName' type='text'></td>"
```

check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSxW7/1/)